# Reading data from XML with attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which is like below:

```
<CPageDataXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<control id="busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl" controltype="business">
    <field controlvaluetype="single" key="busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl_txtEID">
      <valuefield value="709227">E8 - John Doe</valuefield>
    </field>
    <field controlvaluetype="hidden_single" key="busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl_txtEID_Email">
      <valuefield value="_JohnDoe@Wonder.com">emailid</valuefield>
    </field>
</control>
<control id="busDelegationFromDate123" controltype="business">
    <field controlvaluetype="single" key="txtCalanderDateWithImage_UserControl">
      <valuefield value="" />
    </field>
</control>
</CPageDataXML>
```

I want to read the value of the valuefield where control id="busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl"

The C# code is:
This is the code for loading the XML:

```
XmlDocument xPagedata=new XmlDocument();
XmlNode xnodePagedata = null;
xPagedata.LoadXml(strPageData);
```

This is the code for SelectSingleNode:

```
string a = xnodePagedata.SelectSingleNode(//Control[@id='busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl']).Attributes["Value"].Value;
```

I have tried to use SelectSingleNode(string) but that is giving me a null reference exception. Kindly suggest how should I go about this one. I am an absolute beginer on XML.

Comment: What are you using for reading/parsing the XML? Are you using Linq-to-XML? Do you pay attention to your `xmlns`? Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Please show what you've tried - and I'd recommend using LINQ to XML, personally... you shouldn't need XPath for this at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet he cannot use `System.XML.Linq` namespace. do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way using the same approach :

```
string a = 
    xnodePagedata.SelectSingleNode("//control[@id='busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl']/field/valuefield/@value")
                 .Value;
```

**UPDATE :**

In case there are multiple `<valuefield>` in one `<control>` and you want all `value`s, use `SelectNodes()` for example :

```
var values =
    xPagedata.SelectNodes("//control[@id='busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl']/field/valuefield/@value");
foreach (XmlNode value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
}
```

Comment: The first statement actually worked for me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XDocument` : use `Descendants("control")` to get all controls then filter them using the `Where` clause then use `SelectMany` to get a flattened collection of values of valuefield.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

var result = doc.Descendants("control")
                .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("id") == "busRowOAppr2EIDLookUpUserControl")
                .SelectMany(i => i.Descendants("valuefield")
                                  .Select(j => j.Attribute("value")))
                .ToList();
```

And this is the result:

```
result  Count = 2    
[0] {value="709227"}    
[1] {value="_JohnDoe@Wonder.com"}
```

Comment: Hi. Are XMLDocument and XDocument same things ? I have used XMLDocument to load the XML.

Comment: No they aren't. It suggest using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`

Comment: I added the System.XML.Linq reference to the project. But when try to use that namespace in my page intellisense doesn't show System.XML.Linq.

Comment: you should add a reference to `System.XML.Linq.dll`

Comment: What about `System.XML.dll`?

Comment: That too was added.Still no luck.

Comment: I am using 3.5 version. Any other solution using XMLDocument ?

Comment: Cant do that. I have to keep the system intact.

Comment: The namespace is System.Xml.Linq, not System.XML.Linq.